# What is the equivalent to the svn command "Update to revision ..." when using git?

Tags: git, svn

I have difficulty moving from svn to git. How can I go back to a specific revision number locally with git? With svn I use "update to revision ..." to work with an older version of my project. What is the common procedure in this case when using git?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to [`svn update --revision <revision>`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) is [`git checkout <revision>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout). Where [`revision`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) can be a commit ID, branch, tag, date, or a number of other things. See [Revision Selection in Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) for more.

You can use `git checkout -` to return to your last checkout.

When you check out a commit ID you will be in a ["detached HEAD state"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head). HEAD being the reference to the currently checked out commit. Unlike Subversion, Git history truly has branches and you can make commits on top of any commit you like. While in a detached HEAD state any new commits you make will have no reference and can be lost (though not immediately deleted and they can be recovered) if you don't remember the commit ID. You can solve this by making a branch or tag at your new commits.

A major difference is that while `svn update` will talk with the server, `git checkout` only works with your local repository. It will not fetch any new changes from the server. This instead must be done explicitly with `git fetch`. The rough equivalent to `svn update` with no revision is `git pull`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, that was exactly what I was looking for.